# Adhering to logging standard while using Google Guice?

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, guice

The Java docs for [Logger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) indicate that the logger name should be based on the class name.  Google Guice handles this in [BinderImpl.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#rd__TNh_ZrM/svn/trunk/src/com/google/inject/BinderImpl.java&q=member.getDeclaringClass&exact_package=http://google-guice.googlecode.com) where it does the following:

```
return member == null
      ? Logger.getAnonymousLogger()
      : Logger.getLogger(member.getDeclaringClass().getName());
```

However, since it's getting a new logger for each class, I would lose access to whatever [Handler's](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) may have been added to my logger.

What's the best way to handle both having the class name used within the logger and having a standard set of handlers applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution actually has nothing to do with Guice, but rather, is based on how the logging classes work in Java.

Loggers are created in a hierarchy, thus, logger `x.y.z` is a child of `x.y`, all the way up the chain to the root logger whose name is the *empty string*.  Each logger inherits properties, like its logging level, from its parent.

Thus, in order to set the log level globally (or to set handlers globally), simply set them on the root logger:

```
LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
Logger rootLogger = logManager.getLogger("");
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
rootLogger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
```

Once that's done, any injected loggers will have their properties derived from the root logger and any parent loggers that may exist.  For more information on the basics, see the [LogManager documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

A `config` property also exists.  Per the LogManager documentation:

> A property "config". This property is
>   intended to allow arbitrary
>   configuration code to be run. The
>   property defines a whitespace or comma
>   separated list of class names. A new
>   instance will be created for each
>   named class. The default constructor
>   of each class may execute arbitrary
>   code to update the logging
>   configuration, such as setting logger
>   levels, adding handlers, adding
>   filters, etc.

This implies that there are multiple solutions to the problem as I could have also used a configuration class.